# Ionic 5 / Angular 8 - Casting problem from any to my custom type

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular8, ionic5

In my Ionic 5 project I have the following problem: 
I think I have a casting problem.
In my view I want to show language flag icons only if the selected-language property does not match the language itself. The problem is, that when starting the app for the first time all three icons are shown!

I have the following view:

```
<ion-toolbar color="secondary">
    <div class="flags">
      <ion-buttons slot="end" *ngIf="!loading">
        <ion-button *ngIf="selectedLanguage != 'de'" fill="clear" color="dark"
          class="ion-no-padding button-padding flag" (click)="changeLanguage('de')">
          <ion-icon src="../../../assets/flag-icons/de.svg"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button *ngIf="selectedLanguage != 'en'" fill="clear" color="dark"
          class="ion-no-padding button-padding flag" (click)="changeLanguage('en')">
          <ion-icon src="../../../assets/flag-icons/en.svg"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button *ngIf="selectedLanguage != 'nl'" fill="clear" color="dark"
          class="ion-no-padding button-padding flag" (click)="changeLanguage('nl')">
          <ion-icon src="../../../assets/flag-icons/nl.svg"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </div>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

In a settings service I use the following function to get a language string from the local storage:

```
async getSetting(type: string) {
    let result;
    try {
      result = await this.storage.get('_setting_' + type);
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

In my view I want to set the selected language:

```
export type AcceptedLanguage = 'de' | 'en' | 'nl';
```

In my page component I declare and initialise the selectedLanguage as follows:

```
selectedLanguage: AcceptedLanguage = 'de';
```

ngOnInit is defined the following way:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this._loading$ = this.loadingIndicationService.loading$.subscribe(
      (loading) => {
        console.log('loading subscribed in startscreen');
        this.loading = loading;
      }
    );

    this.selectedLanguage = await this.settingsService.getLanguage();

  }
```

I already fixed it by making a switch case around the lang like this:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this._loading$ = this.loadingIndicationService.loading$.subscribe(
      (loading) => {
        console.log('loading subscribed in startscreen');
        this.loading = loading;
      }
    );

    const lang = await this.settingsService.getLanguage();

    switch (lang) {
      case 'de':
        this.selectedLanguage = 'de';
        break;
      case 'en':
        this.selectedLanguage = 'en';
        break;
      case 'nl':
        this.selectedLanguage = 'nl';
        break;
      default:
        this.selectedLanguage = 'nl';
        break;
    }
  }
```

But that's not a good solution! What is a good solution for this? And why do we have this issue? And why does the switch case fix the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't need the  case 'nl':
        this.selectedLanguage = 'nl';
        break; but also remember it's case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Here is why in your first case all 3 *ngIf conditioned templates are shown and then why switch case "fixes it":

Your initial code:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this._loading$ = this.loadingIndicationService.loading$.subscribe(
      (loading) => {
        console.log('loading subscribed in startscreen');
        this.loading = loading;
      }
    );

    this.selectedLanguage = await this.settingsService.getLanguage();

  }
```

Your code initialized "selectedLanguage" with the default value ('de') originally and should there be no attempt to read from Storage via Promise  - you would see only 2 out of 3 templates.

The issue is that in the above code 'selectedLanguage' gets assigned with a Promise pending resolution after the data is retrieved from the Storage.

And unresolved pending Promise is not equal to the 'de' string value anymore.

In your switch case you are using the variable 'lang' and await for Promise to be resolved into actual string and only then you are assigning it to the property 'selectedLanguage', which prevents the issue as selectedLanguage remains as 'de' until promise is fully resolved.

Here is a great example [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) demonstrating in your console that initial value that variable obtains is unresolved (pending) Promise:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function f1() {
  var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
  console.log(x); // initially returns Promise pending, then 10
}

f1();
```

Just paste this into your console (devtools in Chrome) to see whats happening.

So your initial code can be fine as well if you would only assign the value after it is resolved this way:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this._loading$ = this.loadingIndicationService.loading$.subscribe(
      (loading) => {
        console.log('loading subscribed in startscreen');
        this.loading = loading;
      }
    );

    this.settingsService.getLanguage().then(selectedLanguage => {
        if (selectedLanguage) {
            this.selectedLanguage = selectedLanguage;
        }
    })

  }
```

UPDATE:

I tried to recreate your use case here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-ab6d6y

My suspicion that in your code there might be something else going on that prevents the behavior you want. Feel free to play around.

Comment: That doesn’t solve my problem. The three language buttons are still there even after the asynchronous solution with .then.

Comment: Hmm, can you share how exactly you are initializing the value selectedLanguages? based on the code shared so far the only one explanation why its not solving your case can be that the storage may have a null value stored. I will update the code to reflect this.

Comment: basically I added check for the value retrieved from the Storage to be true and only if so apply it. If you can please add console.logs and share what value changes this property (selectedLanguage) has during your app start.

Comment: added stackblitz FYI. Check it out, I played around with different conditions and added || fallback and the code seems to work the way you expect it.